# Role not adding to player

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So I have this code which should assign a role to a player but it doesn't, the player is defined but the error says that the role "isn't a role nor a snowflake", how do I fix this?

```js
var newrole = msg.guild.createRole({ name: channelname, color: 'PURPLE', }).then(console.log).catch(console.error);
                  msg.member.addRole(newrole);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```js
msg.guild
 .createRole({ name: channelname, color: 'PURPLE' })
 .then((role) => {
  msg.member.addRole(role);
 })
 .catch(console.error);
```

[`Guild.createRole()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/v11/class/Guild?scrollTo=createRole) returns a promise with the created role as an argument, which you can use in the callback.